# JMS Serializer, add json root element

Tags: json, zend-framework, serialization, frameworks, jms

I use JMS Serializer to serialize my Doctrine PersistentCollection.

```
$coll = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\MyEntity')->findAll();
return $this->getResponse()->setContent($serializer->serialize($coll, 'json'));
```

How can I add root element to this response?

Comment: Hi. I'm looking for the same response for an usage of JMS serializer in symfony2. I don't know if it's the same in zend but in symfony you have a `config\serializer\Entity.MyEntity.yml` file that let us configure the serialization. in that file you can put a `xml_root_name`but i can't find the same for json. Any ideas ?

Comment: Yes, it;s only possible to add root element in xml serialization. I can't find for json too. I solved this by decoding json string to array, next I added parent element in array and finally I encode array to json.

Comment: @Łukasz, if you were able to solve this, I think it would be better to post it as answer here so that people will know that this question/problem had been solved already.